# How to apply Figma Drop Shadow in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

So I have `Drop Shadow` in Figma file and I want to implement it in my android project. In xml there is `CardView` where I can apply `android:elevation`, for example it is `android:elevation="8dp"` but shadow is more rigid than in Figma file. Is there any way to set shadow as it shown in Figma?

[image: Drop Shadow]